# Fast bit string generation given indices

Tags: python-3.x, loops, enumerate, bitstring

Here a is a list, for example `[34, 52, 57]`.

The function takes in this list and creates a bit string of length 64, where every index is a 0 except at the given indices.

So it would look like `[0,0,....1,...1,..1,..0,0,0]` where only at indices `[34, 52, 57]` we have ones.

```
def bit_string_gen(a):

    bit_string = []
    for key, value in enumerate(range(64)):
        if key in a:
            bit_string.append(1)
        else:
            bit_string.append(0)

    return bit_string
```

Is there a better way to do this, maybe using `lambda` or `map` or `itertools` instead of `enumerate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a solution using map/lambda, here's a one-liner:

`map(lambda x: 1 if x in [34, 52, 57] else 0, range(0, 64))`

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your approach is that you:

- use an `if` statement for *every bit*; and
- use the `in` test which can be rather expensive.

A beter method can be:

```
def bit_string_gen(a):
    bit_string = [0]*64
    for value in a:
        bit_string[value] = 1
    return bit_string
```

So here you iterate only over the values of `a`, and you set these bits to `1`.

Nevertheless it is a bit weird to encode this with a *list of `int`s*. A more compact way to do this is to encode this *binary* on an integer. For instance by using:

```
def bit_string_gen(a):
    bit_string = 0
    for value in a:
        bit_string |= 1 << value
    return bit_string
```

So in the last case if you set the bits like in your sample input, you obtain:

```
>>> bin(bit_string_gen([34, 52, 57]))
'0b1000010000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000'
>>> hex(bit_string_gen([34, 52, 57]))
'0x210000400000000'
```